# nginx config with spa and subdirectory root

Tags: nginx, single-page-application, aurelia

I always seem to have problems with nginx configurations. My SPA is located at /mnt/q/app (pushstate is enabled) and the frontend root is located at client/public. Everything should be mapped to index.html, where the app picks up the route and decides what to do.

Full path to the index is `/mnt/q/app/client/public/index.html`.

I think I ran out of options by now. No matter what I do, I just get a 404 back from nginx, I think the configuration is simple enought and have no clue what's wrong.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.dev;

    root /mnt/q/app;

    location / {
      root /client/public;
      try_files $uri @rewrites =404;
    }

    location @rewrites {
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `nginx` views the file system from the root, then the `root` should be set to `/mnt/q/app/client/public`, and not either of the two values you are using.

The last element of the `try_files` directive can be a default action (e.g. `/index.html`), a named location or a response code. You have a named location in the penultimate element - which will be ignored.

Your named location should work, but is unnecessary, as `try_files` is capable of implementing it more simply. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

For example:

```
root /mnt/q/app;

location / {
    root /mnt/q/app/client/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /api {
}

location /auth {
}
```

The `$uri/` element will add a trailing `/` to directories, so that the `index` directive can work - you do not have to add it if you do not need it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'd however like to add multiple locations in the future. For example, I'll add api and auth components, which I'd like to be at /api and /auth, while the path should be at /mnt/q/app/api/ and /mnt/q/app/auth respectively.

I'm not sure if I can do that with this approach. I used this gist as a "template": https://gist.github.com/aotimme/5006831

Comment: The local path is formed by concatenating the `root` value with the URI, so the `/api` and `/auth` blocks would use the same value for `root` (which can be inherited from the outer block). I presumed that `/index.html` is the URI for the file mentioned in your question, which needs a different value for `root`. See updates.