# Is there anything special I need to consider when reloading a page rendered by react-router to get the expected behavior on refresh?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app, and I'm using react-router, I have a few nested routers, that seem to work fine.

However, when I refresh the page, even though the URL of my browser is something like `/admin/users/blah/` nothing is loaded by react-router, it's as if none of the `<Route>` components get triggered when the page is refreshed by the user. I see my site's navigation menu, but the content that is supposed to be rendered with a router is just blank, again, as if no `<Route>` matched the current URL.

Are there any special considerations or boilerplate I need to add in order to have the expected behavior?

I would expect react-router to match the `<Route>` components again, and render according to my browser's URL, but it doesn't do that.

Comment: did you set up your backend for a a single page app (SPA)? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44098136/1176601 is about nginx => serve the `index.html` for all unknown routes at least, instead of HTTP 404, unless you want some server side rendering (SSR)

Comment: This is on my development machine. React is being served via `npm run start` on port 3000, and the backend is served by rails which is running on my local machine in development mode on port 3001, I believe it's just using Puma for the dev server.

Comment: don't know anything about Puma, only that [create react app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) comes with preconfigured webpack-dev-server that works as expected for client-side-only routing on localhost

Comment: So under normal circumstances, react-router should be able to re-render the page I was on previously, before I had initiated a browser refresh?

Comment: ehm, no idea what you consider "normal"

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue, I had multiple nested `<Router>` elements. You only actually need one. You can nest as many `<Switch>` elements as you want, though.